# How to count the directories of a folder in two level in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command, debian

I would like to count ONLY the directories of a folder. For example:

I have this structure:

- Main_folder

  - Folder

    - **Folder_1**

      - Another_file
  - Folder

    - **File_2**

      ```
      - Another_file
      ```
    - **File_3**

      ```
      - Another_file

      - Another_file
      ```

I need a command that counts only the bold files. In this case the result would be "3".

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. Hope it works

```
find <path> -type d  -printf '%d\n' | grep 2 | wc -l
```

> %d     File's depth in the directory tree; 0 means the file is a
> starting-point.